# Where to add custom claims when using SSO in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I setup my OpenID Connect authentication like following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
  .AddCookie()
  .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
  {
      option.ClientId = config.ClientId;
      option.Authority = String.Format(config.AadInstance, config.Tenant);
  });
```

In my configuration file, I have list of users with elevated permissions which I want to reflect in the claims.

**Where is the best place to add custom claims to the Identity?**

Comment: I know there is ClaimsTransformer middleware and `IClaimsTransformer`, but there is lack of up to date documentation. I know authentication has changes in aspnetcore 2.0, so I better ask. The more details you provide the better.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core2, you can use "IClaimsTransformation". Implement this interface and then in your startup.cs add following line provided your class name is "ClaimsTransformer".

```
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```